# What is the pressure of a gas required to ionize the gas using an electron gun?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, atoms

How dense does a gas (Argon in particular ) have to be to in order to ionize it using electron bombardment and weak magnetic fields. Is there a correlation with the density of a gas and the easiness to ionize the gas ?

Answer (score 7):

Paschen's Law: The striking voltage (to ionize and start an electrical discharge) or breakdown voltage of a gas depends on the pressure and and also distance between the electrodes .

[image]

at very low pressures the mean free path of the free electron is many times longer than the electrode gap, ie, most of the electrons fail to hit and ionize a gas atom/molecule in the vicinity of the gap to create a conducting path.

you can see a sweet spot in Paschen's Law. at pressures higher than this spot the mean free path of the electron is so short, it cannot acquire enough kinetic energy to ionize the atom/molecule before colliding with it. an electron experiences an accelerating force in an electric field, and must be free to accelerate to a kinetic energy of at least the first ionization energy of the target particle.